# Create General Custom Web.config reader

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, web-config, asp.net-webcontrol

I need your help on this. I've seen a lot of articles on how to create a custom web.config reader (like this: [Custom ConfigurationSections in .NET 2.0 .config Files](http://jopinblog.wordpress.com/2007/04/20/custom-configurationsections-in-net-20-config-files/)). However, is it possible to have something general where I can just pass the configuration section and keys? Moreover, how is this done?

Sample web.config 1:

```
<Section1>
   <add Key1="value1-A" Key2="value1-B" Key3="value1-C"/>
   <add Key1="value2-A" Key2="value2-B" Key3="value2-C"/>
</Section1>
```

Sample web.config 2:

```
<Section2>
   <add Key1="value1-A" Key2="value1-B" Key3="value1-C"/>
   <add Key1="value2-A" Key2="value2-B" Key3="value2-C"/>
</Section2>
```

Comment: with multiple keys in a line? or key-value pair like <add key="mykey" value= "myvalues"/>

Comment: with multiple keys. but it has to be generic so that it can be used anywhere. i think it's a bit weird if we just specify it to a certain config section right?

Comment: Can you describe a usage?

Comment: there are some config files that have this kind of scenario. so what i want is a certain class in which i can pass any config section and get the values of the keys (i.e., key1, key 2, key3).